# How to configure micronaut with newrelic open telemetry

Tags: micronaut, open-telemetry

I'm trying to work out how to configure the micronaut framework with open telemetry. I've created a project which is currently not working here https://github.com/CraftyFella/micronaut-opentelemetry

I feel I've done something fundametally wrong though as while i'm getting traces appear in new relic, they don't contain any of the [micronaut configured custom spans](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-tracing/latest/guide/#annotations) using the micronaut annotations.

The documentation is quite light for open telemetry on the micronaut website, so I'm hoping someone in that community can enlighten me into the steps to create a micronaut example that pushes open telemetry info.

Answer (score 2):

Jack here from New Relic. Disclosure: I work on the [opentelemetry-java](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java) project but haven't used micronaut before.

I dug into the code and found [DefaultOpenTelemetryFactory](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-tracing/blob/master/tracing-opentelemetry/src/main/java/io/micronaut/tracing/opentelemetry/DefaultOpenTelemetryFactory.java), which appears to be the code that translates `application.yml` configuration to OpenTelemetry configuration. It mostly just relies on the built in [autoconfigure](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/tree/main/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure) options, with some code that translates yaml to the flattened options expected by OpenTelemetry autoconfigure. So:

```
otel:
  traces:
    exporter: otlp
  metrics:
    exporter: otlp
```

is equivalent to:

```
export OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER=otlp
export OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER=otlp
```

New Relic maintains an [example](https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-opentelemetry-examples/tree/main/java/agent-nr-config) that shows how to configure OpenTelemetry to export to New Relic. The minimal configuration equivalent in micronaut yaml config would be:

```
otel:
  traces:
    exporter: otlp
  metrics:
    exporter: otlp
  logs:
    exporter: otlp
  exporter:
    otlp:
      endpoint: https://otlp.nr-data.net:4317
      headers: api-key=<YOUR_LICENSE_KEY>
      compression: gzip
      # New Relic requires metrics to be delta
      metrics_temporality_preference: delta
```

I've successfully tested this configuration in the sample app you provided.

(BTW, I encourage you to open an issue with the [micronaut-tracing](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-tracing) project explaining what was missing in the documentation :).)

Comment: Interesting thanks. I also got it working today but the micronaut people mentioned that the logging exporter isn’t working and you have to do that manually. I used one of the projects in your repo to help fix that. Can we sync up on my support ticket in new relic and then I can update my example and maybe we can add another example to your repo? My case no is #00063804

Comment: @CraftyFella Did you manage to send JVM metrics this way? I used the same configuration, my application is sending requests to my APM server's metrics endpoint, but it is not sending any useful information.

Comment: Yes it sends the micrometer metrics or your own custom metrics . You can use the metrics explorer build into new relic.  I’ve updated the repo so it all seems to be working.  Some other members of the team had success with the open telemetry Java agent.

Comment: There is some extra config you have to turn on to make that work though. I’ll dig it out for you and update the repo